# 1995 Accord Ex Battery keeps disconnecting

Tags: honda, battery, starting, accord, battery-cable

So my battery keeps disconnecting, and has been for a couple of days now, resulting in the lights on the dash lighting up for a brief moment and then turning back off and not the car not starting. The positive terminal is more than likely close to the age of the car, pretty loose, and what I assumed was causing the disconnects as I tightened the negative one and it does not move. I would tighten down the positive clamp and it still be able to slip off the post. Guy at AutoZone gave me some post shims to fit over it, installed it this morning and was able to tighten down the positive clamp, but the car was still not starting. It still took some jiggling both cables to get it to turn over and it did start. Any solutions as to why it still wont start? I had the battery tested and it was still good.

Comment: Did you clean all the oxides off the battery terminal and the clamps before you reconnected them?

Answer (score 1):

Another loose connection on the other end of one of the cables is a distinct possibility.

Otherwise it could commonly be an internally broken cable.

Test and find out.